# merkle root 2 codes

Tags: mining-pools, python, block-header, merkle-tree, block-hash

While trying to calculate the **merkle root** in python from the data i got from the mining pool.... i found there are 2 different codes.

**code 1:**

```
def build_merkle_root(coinbase_hash_bin, merkle_branch):
    merkle_root = coinbase_hash_bin
    for h in merkle_branch:
        merkle_root = hashlib.sha256(hashlib.sha256(merkle_root + binascii.unhexlify(h)).digest()).digest()
    return binascii.hexlify(merkle_root).decode('utf-8')
```

This is explained in shlushpool stratum document [**here**](https://slushpool.com/help/manual/stratum-protocol) and also in an altcoin sia mining protocol [**here**](https://siamining.com/stratum) . **So i think it should be correct.**
But there is another piece of code below,

**code 2:**

```
def build_merkle_root(hash_list):
if len(hash_list) < 2:
    return hash_list[0]
new_hash_list = []

# Process pairs. For odd length, the last is skipped
for i in range(0, len(hash_list) - 1, 2):
    new_hash_list.append(hash2(hash_list[i], hash_list[i + 1]))

# odd, hash last item twice
if len(hash_list) % 2 == 1:
    new_hash_list.append(hash2(hash_list[-1], hash_list[-1]))

return build_merkle_root(new_hash_list)
#==========================================================================
def hash2(a, b):
     # Reverse inputs before and after hashing due to big-endian / little-endian nonsense
     a1 = binascii.unhexlify(a)[::-1]
     b1 = binascii.unhexlify(b)[::-1]
     h = hashlib.sha256(hashlib.sha256(a1 + b1).digest()).digest()

     return binascii.hexlify(h[::-1])
```

**This one looks more logical** from the merkle tree structure point of view which is hashing each pair separately.

For testing them, Taking below as an example of the job obtained from a pool....

```
[{'id': None,
  'method': 'mining.notify',
  'params': ['59bc8dfc00003829',
   'ceeefd1381f491d9a0ba90b26a495a225e8bfc9f00ecc4250000000000000000',
   '01000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ffffffff3503226b07000455abc259040bf12d090c',
   '0a636b706f6f6c112f736f6c6f2e636b706f6f6c2e6f72672fffffffff035976a953000000001976a914fc6123f4bfd3a840b4387ab90e9801e98fb17cf888ac8756d800000000001976a914f4cbe6c6bb3a8535c963169c22963d3a20e7686988ac0000000000000000266a24aa21a9edc963e012cb380138e3d16283a094454782879557714d3b0d73fecfe612d01f0600000000',
   ['b32abe89497354ceaa2dff35cc41995d58c19893d517e92e30b4ead75a66970c',
    'ca93a597a29860178f4cd01326f43b080f516f3f81ba6b86b0ff35f5cb206b7f',
    '213f7e41a5b228ec554c1a2e3fe18b1f3e1c23821b1b2b3aa1319d3d616044ca',
    '0941052c2e5864e57a18bfc82d1e7ab15740d4ed7b852cda92bffd3ff622e59d',
    '7ad5af30a3daa89c1244016227cde139d5d54232a673cbf7954f6a1aa26bbc05',
    'e24a96489d5782c6bcde209952a12826cd225b97b9a3ad3142c87dd062136d0b',
    '383a433dc503c8ab4b7beb9dc4a3e07811a1cb9681e2da019cec16966fc727be',
    'f10804628f630bcead6cd1b667d4352cdfb93aea382662456c2caadda3e1b0c9',
    '03e9bf5b6053fe86d272dac8c2a32f08ace6d045799ae499ed7087af21c737c6',
    '3cf338c75d7ef47b0c029d16b5b02340a62ce0a7846910175b021d919dcccc6f',
    '40319623d80cae8a5b1a3e319a962110a08ff40daf40ebf421b9454f20e54dcc',
    'c29e3826153dfc1d10e9e173281d21ad2103bba86bc2930440e7258afca2b957'],
   '20000000',
   '1800ff18',
   '59c2ab55',
   False]}]
```

Code 1 gives me merkle root as `7cbd55a748aa8e778e0795e33d5bd5a07c9f465cd3de1fef3bf36ea3ac4d56f9` while
 Code 2 gives as `6681ae1409685d71a51ced80ae0c7eacb78d5facb401ece2287543b6cc17e4cf`
Since both are not same, **so which one is wrong** ? I needed merkle root for block header.

In both the above cases, I took extranonce2 all zeros as `0000000000000000` and build coinbase as `01000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ffffffff3503226b07000455abc259040bf12d090cff47c35900000000000000000a636b706f6f6c112f736f6c6f2e636b706f6f6c2e6f72672fffffffff035976a953000000001976a914fc6123f4bfd3a840b4387ab90e9801e98fb17cf888ac8756d800000000001976a914f4cbe6c6bb3a8535c963169c22963d3a20e7686988ac0000000000000000266a24aa21a9edc963e012cb380138e3d16283a094454782879557714d3b0d73fecfe612d01f0600000000` which gives a coinbase hash of `20d0b9a72f1e940e29b064e428f5e037f948c9ede27dfb7e77b1df7d289d1861`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stratum protocol gives you some hashes of specific branches in the merkle tree. They may not be at the same depth in the tree (and I don't think they are). They are only provided so that the miner can change the coinbase transaction by incrementing the extranonce and then incorporating it into the merkle root. The Code 1 merkle root should be the correct one since that is the method that the Stratum protocol docs tells you to do. The other code is for creating the merkle root from a list of transactions, not a list of branch hashes as Stratum provides.

Comment: So the merkle_root obtained from Code1 "7cbd55a748aa8e778e0795e33d5bd5a07c9f465cd3de1fef3bf36ea3ac4d56f9" will be used directly in Block Header or it is in display format same as https://blockchain.info/ and i will need to reverse the bytes to put it in Block Header.

Comment: It should be usable directly in the block header.